# Zero Actions on a Hopf Module Preserved Under the AntiPode?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra, and $(M,\triangleleft)$ a $H$-module. Now for $m \in M$, and $h \in H$, then is it true in general that
$$
m \triangleleft h = 0 ~~~ \implies ~~~~m \triangleleft S(h) = 0? 
$$
If not, do there exist conditions on $H$ or $M$ under which it is true.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not true. All you need is a right ideal, not closed under $S$. Then you will a cyclic module with a counterexample. The group algebra of $C_3$ over a field with a primitive cubic root of 1 will be an example...

I cannot think of any conditions beyond obvious ones...